# Как изменить регистр букв с помощью регулярного выражения в Notepad++

Tags: регулярные-выражения, pcre

Например, есть много строк вида: `Термин — определение`. Как регулярными выражениями в Notepad++ сделать, чтобы `термин` был написан заглавными (прописными) буквами — `ТЕРМИН`?

Comment: Здесь описано как это сделать:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039226/regex-to-change-to-sentence-case   
или ищите **notepad++ regexp replace uppercase**

Answer (score 7):

Протестировано на Sublime Text 3.

Предположим, «термин» и «определение» состоят из любых символов кроме переноса строки (т. к. согласно условиям автора саму строку составляют "Термин — определение"). Тогда:

*Найти:*

`(.*?)( — .*)`

*Заменить:*

`\U$1\E$2`

*Было:*

```
Россия — Москва

Гаити — Порт-О-Пренс

   Соломоновы острова — Хониара
  4. тринидад и тобаго — Порт-оф-Спейн
```

*Стало:*

```
РОССИЯ — Москва

ГАИТИ — Порт-О-Пренс

   СОЛОМОНОВЫ ОСТРОВА — Хониара
  4. ТРИНИДАД И ТОБАГО — Порт-оф-Спейн
```

*Демонстрация:*

[image: Смена регистра в Sublime Text 3]

*Пояснения:*

`(.*?)` — любые 0 или более символов кроме переноса строки, используется ленивый квантор;
`( — .*)` — пробел — тире — пробел — любые 0 или более символов кроме переноса строки.
`\U$1\E` — содержимое первого подвыражения переводится в верхний регистр;
`$2` — второе подвыражение остаётся неизменным.

С поддержкой шаблона поиска проблем возникнуть не должно, а вот в регулярном выражении замены используются мета-символы изменения регистра:

- `\U` перевести в верхний регистр,
- `\E` первые буквы слов в верхнем регистре,
- `\L` перевести в нижний регистр.

Приведённые в таблице мета-символы замены являются специфичной особенностью некоторых текстовых редакторов, это нестандартное поведение для регулярных выражений.

**Таблица поддержки мета-символов замены**

```
              │  \U │  \E │  \L
──────────────┼─────┼─────┼──────
 Notepad++    │  +  │  -  │  +
 SublimeText3 │  +  │  +  │  +
```

Comment: не работает так. Почему-то... ((

Answer (score 2):

А точно надо регуляркой? Просто там же можно найти все соответствия того, что Вам нужно (ctrl+f) и преобразовать регистр (ctrl+shift+u)